# Fast membership in slices of lists

Tags: python, performance

I have a very large list called 'data' and I need to answer queries equivalent to

```
if (x in data[a:b]):
```

for different values of a, b and x.

Is it possible to preprocess data to make these queries fast

Comment: You might need to add more information as to how `x`, `a` and `b` vary. Many different `x`es for one instance of `[a:b]` or one `x` checked against many different `[a:b]` slices...? Also, is `data` sorted, perhaps?

Comment: I can have many different x for each a, b pair. The list data is not sorted sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## idea

you may create a `dict`. For every element store the sorted list of positions where it occurs.

To answer query: binary search first element that greater or equal `a`, check if it exists and less than `b`

## Pseudocode

Preprocessing:

```
from collections import defaultdict

byvalue = defaultdict(list)

for i, x in enumerate(data):
    byvalue[x].append(i)
```

Query:

```
def has_index_in_slice(indices, a, b):
   r = bisect.bisect_left(indices, a)

   return r < len(indices) and indices[r] < b

def check(byvalue, x, a, b):
    indices = byvalue.get(x, None)
    if not indices: return False

    return has_index_in_slice(indices, a, b)
```

Complexity is `O(log N)` per query here if we suppose that `list` and `dict` have O(1) "get by index" complexity.

Comment: The [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module provides tools to simplify the binary search code and make it much faster.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the commented out code, and made it so that it only searches for the key `x` once, rather than twice. I further made aesthetic changes to make the answer more pythonic (no semicolons, no `!`, `defaultdict` instead of manual check, `enumerate(data)` instead of `range(len(data))`.)

Comment: @nightcracker, thanks. I know I'm writing c++ code using python:)

Comment: Thank you, that looks good. It's a shame python has no binary search tree in its Collections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could preprocess those slices into sets, thereby making membership lookup `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`:

```
check = set(data[a:b])
if x in check:
    # do something
if y in check:
    # do something else
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question. If I'm not mistaken the question wants to preprocess `data` such that in the future membership requests on arbitrary slices are fast, rather than precalculating one set for one particular slice.

Comment: @nightcracker: I'm not sure since he formatted the word `data` differently. You may be right, though - in which case the answer probably would be "no". Unfortunately, phoenix has not reacted to my request for clarification...

Comment: Ah I didn't see your clarification. I do think that since `a, b` are part of the query that they may vary wildy. But the answer is definitely yes, see RiaD's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the list in a database and take advantage of the built in indexing, optimizations and caching. For instance, from the PostgreSQL manual:

> Once an index is created, no further intervention is required: the
>   system will update the index when the table is modified, and it will
>   use the index in queries when it thinks doing so would be more
>   efficient than a sequential table scan.

But you could also use sqlite for simplicity (and availability in Python's standard library). From [Python's documentation, regarding indexing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row):

> A Row instance serves as a highly optimized row_factory for Connection
>   objects. It tries to mimic a tuple in most of its features.
>
> It supports mapping access by column name and index, iteration,
>   representation, equality testing and len().

And elsewhere on that page:

> Row provides both index-based and case-insensitive name-based access
>   to columns with almost no memory overhead. It will probably be better
>   than your own custom dictionary-based approach or even a db_row based
>   solution.